# How to programmatically get all printer models for a given manufacturer on windows?

Tags: c++, winapi, printing, print-spooler-api

I'm trying to enumerate printer models for a given manufacturer.  Windows 'Add Printer' is somehow able to do that - i.e. when a manufacturer is selected in the left list a list of printer models is displayed on the right side.

I'm familiar with EnumPrinters and EnumPrinterDrivers API but neither of the related structures (PRINTER_INFO* and DRIVER_INFO*) contain printer models.
DRIVER_INFO* does contain manufacturer's name but I'm not sure where to find printer models that a corresponding driver supports.

Any suggestions and pointers to on-line docs will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

EnumPrinterDrivers only enumerates *installed* printer drivers. The Add Printer dialog shows available drivers including the built-in drivers not yet installed.

The built-in driver files are in the [Driver Store](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/install/driver-store). For instance, if you click on HP in the left pane, the drivers for HP 910 and 915 are in this INF:

```
C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\prnhp003.inf_amd64_4480210763997eb4\prnhp003.inf
```

To install these you could try the old [Setup API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc185682(v=vs.85).aspx) or new [Windows Installer API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc185688(v=vs.85).aspx).

There doesn't seem to be a public API to enumerate the Driver Store contents, but the [DISM command line tool can](http://www.verboon.info/2010/12/inside-the-windows-7-driver-store/). It will parse all the right folders and INF files (for inbox drivers [if you supply the /all switch to /get-drivers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/commercialize/manufacture/desktop/dism-driver-servicing-command-line-options-s14)) and then you just need to parse the output. E.g.

```
Dism /online /get-drivers /all /format:list >drivers.txt
```

(I did suggest [DriverStore Explorer](https://github.com/lostindark/DriverStoreExplorer) but it turns out that's just a wrapper around the Windows [PnPUtil.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/devtest/pnputil) tool which can't enumerate inbox drivers.)

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I can now see all the built-in drivers/printer models in INF files located in FileRepository\prn* folders. I wish there was an API that could query those files and return a list of printer models found in them.  I think I could parse all INF files in all prn* folders.  However I'm not sure if all and only printer drivers are located in prn* folders.  Do you know if there is any official documentation on the subject (e.g. folder naming convention, etc.)?  I do not need to install the drivers.  I just need a list of printer models grouped by a manufacturer.

Comment: I can't find a public API, but edited my answer to add some tools that can enumerate the Driver Store.